# Gui интерфейс на qt в виде dll

Tags: qt, gui, dll

Возникла проблема такого плана: есть приложение работающее вообще без gui, было решено что к нему нужно запилить этот самый пользовательский интерфейс. Пытаюсь это сделать создав интерфейс, а гуишный класс написанный на qt и реализующий этот интерфейс запихать в dll. Но вот тут самое интересное....а как его запустить? Ведь если выполнить QApplication::exec(), то он будет бесконечно в нем крутиться и не давать выполниться остальному коду, а если не вызывать exec(), то изменения не будут отображаться в окне gui. Как быть?

хедер с интерфейсом

```
struct MyInterface {
virtual int Add(int a, int b) = 0;
virtual void Print() = 0;
```

};

```
extern "C" bool __declspec(dllexport) GetMyInterface(MyInterface** pMyInterface);
typedef bool(*GETINTF)(MyInterface** pMyInterface);

extern "C" bool __declspec(dllexport) FreeMyInterface(MyInterface** pMyInterface);
typedef bool(*FREEINTF)(MyInterface** pMyInterface);
```

реализация функций создания объекта

```
bool GetMyInterface(MyInterface** pMyInterface) {
if (!*pMyInterface) {
    *pMyInterface = new Gui(0);
    return true;
}
return false;
}

bool FreeMyInterface(MyInterface** pMyInterface) {
if (!*pMyInterface) {
    return false;
}
delete *pMyInterface;
pMyInterface = 0;
app.exit();
return true;
}
```

хедер Gui

```
 class Gui : public QObject, public MyInterface
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
Gui(QObject *parent);
~Gui();

public slots:
int Add(int a, int b);
void Print();

private:
int argc;
char** argv;
//QApplication app;
QTextEdit* textEdit;
};
```

реализация gui

```
Gui::Gui(QObject *parent)
: QObject(parent), argc(0), argv(0)//, app(argc, argv)
{
this->textEdit = new QTextEdit;
this->textEdit->show();

this->textEdit->append("I'm QT and I'm alive");
//app.exec();
}

int Gui::Add(int a, int b) {
this->textEdit->append("You check Add function");
return a + b;
}

void Gui::Print() {
this->textEdit->append("I'm QT and I can print everything");
}
```

здесь пытаюсь все это дело подключить и использовать

```
int main()
{
HINSTANCE hDll = LoadLibrary("Library.dll");

MyInterface* myInterface = 0;

if (hDll) {
    std::cout << "Dll load - successful" << std::endl;

    GETINTF GetMyInterface;
    GetMyInterface = (GETINTF)GetProcAddress(hDll, "GetMyInterface");
    if (!GetMyInterface) {
        std::cout << "Load F GetMyInterface - fail" << std::endl;
        FreeLibrary(hDll);
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }

    FREEINTF FreeMyInterface;
    FreeMyInterface = (FREEINTF)GetProcAddress(hDll, "FreeMyInterface");
    if (!FreeMyInterface) {
        std::cout << "Load F FreeMyInterface - fail" << std::endl;
        FreeLibrary(hDll);
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }

    GetMyInterface(&myInterface);

    std::cout << "My interface print - " << myInterface->Add(10, 5)<<std::endl;
    myInterface->Print();

    _getch();

    FreeMyInterface(&myInterface);

    std::cout << Add(2, 3) << std::endl;
    Print("a");
    PrintWSC("a");

}
else {
    std::cout << "Not load dll" << std::endl;
}
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Обязательно делать длл? Можно было бы сделать отдельное гуи приложение, взаимодействующее с работующим консольным каким-либо способом.

Comment: Веселое у Вас приложение. Попробуйте использовать `QCoreApplication::processEvents`

Comment: А если поступить наоборот - консольное приложение оформить загружаемой библиотекой, и в gui-приложении уже дергать оттуда необходимые функции?

Comment: Просто хотя-бы понять как реализовать эту идею. Дело в том, что я в длл создаю класс с гпи унаследованный от QObject, и у меня есть на него указатель. Но без QApplication он работать не может, поэтому просто получить этот указатель в win32 приложении мало, нужно чтоб создавался где то QApplication, когда вообще создавать QApplication в таком случае?

Answer (score 0):

Короче говоря проблема решается достаточно просто, в win32 приложении нужно было вызвать функцию создания Гпи(в которой к слову создаётся и QApplication) в отдельном потоке - вот и все решение...